# Updating other ViewModels and Container form from a PropertyChanged command in one of the UserControls in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I am having a WPF `Window` with a set of UserControls each with it's own ViewModel. And on the ViewModel of the container `Window`, I am having the instances of their ViewModels.

In one of those UserControls, there is a `ComboBox` and on its `SelectionChanged`, I need to update other UserControls as well as the container `Window` (i.e. their corresponding ViewModels).

I tried to scrap the idea of having ViewModels for these user controls and instead have their functionality on ViewModel of the container form, but that doesn't seem right since the user controls actually do quite a lot and it's very complex to have everything on container windows' ViewModel.

Is there any way to achieve this or should I go with "everything on container window's ViewModel" ?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Hint: use any kind of event aggregator/message bus for decoupled messaging...

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek Can you please point me to some examples ?

Comment: You can make model for this. So you get event change some property in model, other view models depend on this property in model

Comment: Sure: [first](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/02/01/caliburn-micro-part-4-the-event-aggregator/), [second](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=The%20Event%20Aggregator), [third](http://chriskoenig.net/2010/07/05/mvvm-light-messaging/), [fourth](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/mvvm-light-whats-messenger) link.

Comment: use @PatrykĆwiek 's suggestion of using a messenger pattern or subscribe to sibling/child `UserControlViewModel` events via a weak event observing pattern from the VM itself and keep the View's out of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve what you want (with a view model for each of your controls) by using `delegate`s. You can find out more about `delegates` from the [Delegates (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) page at MSDN.

Basically, you need to create one or more `delegate`s in your `UserControl` objects... they're great for passing information from parents to children or vice versa:

```
public delegate void ParentNotification(YourDataType dataTypeInstance);
```

Then a getter an setter for each:

```
public ParentNotification OnSelectionChanged { get; set; }
```

Now the window that instantiates the `UserControl` can register a handler for each of these delegates:

```
<YourXmlNamespace:YourUserControl OnSelectionChanged="OnSelectionChangedhandler" />
```

Then add a handler that matches the definition of the `delegate` in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public void OnSelectionChangedhandler(YourDataType dataTypeInstance)
{
    // do something with dataTypeInstance
}
```

The final piece of the puzzle is to call the `delegate` from each `UserControl` after whatever condition has occurred... in this case, the condition is that there has been a selection change:

```
private void ComboBoxSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    YourDataType dataTypeInstance = null;
    if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0) 
    {
        dataTypeInstance = (YourDataType)e.AddedItems[0];
        if (OnSelectionChanged != null) // very important check here
        {
            OnSelectionChanged(dataTypeInstance);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would not propose this approach. (`The final piece of the puzzle is to call the delegate from each UserControl after whatever condition has occurred`) Having the **View evaluate these conditions** would break test-ability and thereby go away from some MVVM advantages of being able to unit test almost all relevant logic. By using the messenger/eventaggregator the UI logic is kept where it belongs(In the VM) and synchronization of that data can happen across VM's directly without the involvement of Views.

Comment: Hey @Viv, while I agree with your point, the question author clearly said that he's using the `SelectionChanged` event in his `UserControl`. It's his choice, so tell him instead.

Comment: I did before adding the comment here as well. Question authors almost always ask questions based on what they know or are aware of / prefer. My comment was not to try to indicate what you're doing is "wrong"(if so I'd have downvoted), but to make sure anyone else in the future just looking at this answer to know there are alternate approaches to solve this entire issue and yield some benefit by doing so.